# OR statement and REGEX in Python

Tags: python, html, regex, html-parsing

I'm using REGEX to compile a list of strings from an HTML doc in Python. The strings are either found inside a td tag, or inside a div tag. I am having problem properly using the REGEX OR to prevent the following problem from happening. If I use:

```
FindStrings= re.compile('<td>(.*?)</td>|padding:0;">(.*?)</div>')
MyStrings = re.findall(FindStrings, str(soup))
print MyStrings
```

I would get something like:

```
[('apple', ''), ('sky', ''), ('red', ''), ('', 'summer'), ('', 'pizza')]
```

I get that the strings on the left side of the brackets are found with `<td>(.*?)</td>` and the one on the right side are found with `</td>|padding:0;">(.*?)</div>`. I would like to know what should be added to the REGEX to get a final list like the one bellow:

```
['apple', 'sky', 'red', 'summer', 'pizza']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of how you're parsing/using regex you can use Python's `itertools` after you've got your list:

```
import itertools

item_list = [("apple", ""), ("sky", ""), ("red", ""), ("", "summer"), ("", "pizza")]
print(item_list)

flat_list = list(itertools.chain(*item_list))
result = filter(None, flat_list)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[('apple', ''), ('sky', ''), ('red', ''), ('', 'summer'), ('', 'pizza')]
['apple', 'sky', 'red', 'summer', 'pizza']
```

Comment: Pfff.  *This* got accepted?  That could have been accomplished by a simple `[ ''.join(x) for x in item_list ]` without any `itertools` or whatever.

Comment: Yes, it did get accepted — and itertools is faster.

Answer (score 4):

[Do not use regex for parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). There are specialized tools for working with the HTML format.

Example using [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) package:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>apple</td>
            <td>sky</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>red</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div>summer</div>
    <div>pizza</div>
</body>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print [item.text for item in soup.find_all(['td', 'div'])]
```

Prints:

```
[u'apple', u'sky', u'red', u'summer', u'pizza']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can process the result of the regex to the way that you want.
Something like this -

```
#Result of regex in MyStrings
>>> MyStrings = [('apple', ''), ('sky', ''), ('red', ''), ('', 'summer'), ('', 'pizza')]
>>> [s[0] if s[1]=='' else s[1] for s in MyStrings]
['apple', 'sky', 'red', 'summer', 'pizza']
```

Comment: No, he wants to extract directly the proper results, via regex